# Remove object by id from array in React hooks state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How would I remove a specific id in this setup. I tried to use filter: `setNotesDummyData(notesDummyData.filter((o) => { myCondition }));` inside the `onChangeItemName` function but can't return right conditions so only one item will get removed.

```
const NotesContainer = ({

}) => {
  const [notesDummyData, setNotesDummyData] = useState([
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'Holland',
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      title: 'Russia',
    },
  ]);

  const onChangeItemName = (itemId) => {

    //Remove item with specific itemId

  };
```

Comment: You need to return your condition to the filter and in wrapping your condition in {}-brackets, it does not get returned and thus not filtered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const onChangeItemName = (itemId) => {
    setNotesDummyData(notesDummyData.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));
};
```

Comment: Yes, this works. How would I go about if I would like to .splice away that item?